# Nginx Server using for hosting NodeJs applications

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment

I am a newbie developing a nodeJs application and has bundled it using browsify to a file bundle.js and want to deploy it in Nginx. 
I have given the reference to the bundle.js inside the index.html(shown below), which I am not sure is the right way to do.
The nginx.conf file is :

```
server {

    listen 8056;
    root html/node_server;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    }
```

The index.html file and bundle.js files are placed in htm\node_server folder and I am trying to hit port 8056 like *http://localhost:8056* . But showing error :

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined* in the bundle.js : 78869

in the browser console, but nothing in Nginx error log .

bundle.js : 78869 is

```
`/**
 * Request prototype.
 * @public
 */

var req = Object.create(http.IncomingMessage.prototype)`
```

My index.html file is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DEV</title>
  <base href="/">

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

NodeJs file :

```
   var sql = require("mssql");
 var express = require('express');
 var http = require("http");
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //Enabling CORS 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});
app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.send('Working');
});
```

Bundle.js in more detail :

```
`/**
 * Module dependencies.
 * @private
 */

var accepts = require('accepts');
var deprecate = require('depd')('express');
var isIP = require('net').isIP;
var typeis = require('type-is');
var http = require('http');
var fresh = require('fresh');
var parseRange = require('range-parser');
var parse = require('parseurl');
var proxyaddr = require('proxy-addr');

/**
 * Request prototype.
 * @public
 */

var req = Object.create(http.IncomingMessage.prototype) ---- Error here

/**
 * Module exports.
 * @public
 */

module.exports = req

/**
 * Return request header.
 *
 * The `Referrer` header field is special-cased,
 * both `Referrer` and `Referer` are interchangeable.
 *
 * Examples:
 *
 *     req.get('Content-Type');
 *     // => "text/plain"
 *
 *     req.get('content-type');
 *     // => "text/plain"
 *
 *     req.get('Something');
 *     // => undefined
 *
 * Aliased as `req.header()`.
 *
 * @param {String} name
 * @return {String}
 * @public
 */

req.get =
req.header = function header(name) {
  if (!name) {
    throw new TypeError('name argument is required to req.get');
  }

  if (typeof name !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError('name must be a string to req.get');
  }

  var lc = name.toLowerCase();

  switch (lc) {
    case 'referer':
    case 'referrer':
      return this.headers.referrer
        || this.headers.referer;
    default:
      return this.headers[lc];
  }
};
`
```

Am I missing something?
If more details are required, kindly do comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted my previous answers, as I had misunderstood your problem.

The issue it seems is that the `http` library is not suited to be browserified. In other words, there is some JavaScript in your `bundle.js` file that cannot run in a web browser.

Could you give some context to the failing lines in the `bundle.js` file?

This issue does not seem to have anything to do with your node.js / nginx setup.

Comment: Hi Tomahaug, Thank you. Please see my nodeJs file (edited the question)(which actually is the server side of my angular 2 application). I think I did something terribly wrong there as I was using express. So do we have to use http server instead of express? Or Is there a way I can use express?

Comment: Hi, I have added the context to the failing lines in the bundle.js file in the answer which is edited.

Comment: Hi Amal, sorry for my late reply. It seems that you're trying to bundle the node.js http library to the browser – this cannot be done. The http library is a server-side library and doesn't have any use in the client (browser).

Bundling and optimizing js files is (in general) only for client-side JavaScript and not server-side JavaScript. So you do not need to bundle anything to run your Node.js server. 

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be better for you start node.js app localy on the server and than configure nginx as reverse proxy ?
Here is detailed tutorial how to do it:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Hi, 

So you mean, I have to start the node.js app on my express server in a system and use nginx as a reverse  server?